# Random sampling of non-overlapping substrings of length k

Tags: string, random, language-agnostic, sample

Given a string of length *n*, how would I (pseudo)randomly sample *m* substrings of size *k* such that none of the sampled substrings overlap? Most of my scripting experience is in Perl, but an easy-to-run solution in any common language will suffice.

Comment: Divide string into samples of desired length; possibly by populating array, and then `my $rnd = $array[int rand @array]`

Comment: I think I would approach it by considering that there are `n-m*k` characters that _will not_ be used, and `m+1` gaps into which they can go.  Pick the lengths of those `m+1` gaps so they add up to exactly `n-m*k`.  (This way, you don't need to consider overlaps.)

Comment: I'm assuming the substrings need to be contiguous (otherwise it would be very easy to do with an iterator)?

Comment: @ali_m Yes, by substring I mean a string of *k* contiguous characters from the original string.

Comment: why are you doing this?  I'm not sure I can think of an algorithm that wouldn't bias against selecting characters very near the beginning or end of the string, so it isn't going to be "fair"

Comment: @ysth The strings I'm working with represent DNA sequences from different species, and I suspect the sequences from different species have significantly different composition. I'm going to run a glm to test this, and I want to separate the within-species effects from the between-species effects--thus I need multiple measurements for each sequence (or multiple substrings for each string). As long as the sampled substrings are pseudo-random, I don't think this will be a problem for the glm.

Comment: @cjm yes, this how it should be done, please take a look at my answer to the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784258/get-n-random-non-overlapping-substrings-of-length-k/58785622#58785622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a character that cannot occur in the input, e.g. `X`, just:

```perl
my $size = 20;
my $count = 20;
my $mark = 'X';
my $input = 'CCACGCATTTTTGTTCATTGTTCTGGCTTCTTACAAGGTTCAGTAGACTTTGTAACACAGTTGTGTCTCTCACAGATTGGCAGATGTTTGGTAAAGGATTGACTTTTCAGCCAACTCATGGGAAAGTGAAATAATGTAAAAAACAGGAAGAATACAGTTTTAGGCCTTTCAAGTGAGGCATGGCTTTCAGCTCTTGGCAAGAACAGGCAAGGAGATGCAAGTTTTAGGACTCTAAGAGGCTAGGCTTTTCAAAGTGCTTCTCTCCCCTTCACCCTCCTTCAGTTACAGCACCAAGCACCACCGAGGTGTTACCTGCAGCCTCACTCTCTACCTGGTTGTGGGATCCTGCCACTTCCTTAACCCACACTGAGTTCCTTGTGGTTCACAGGGTCACACAGAGGGCTGTAGAGATACAAAAGATATATGTGATTTTATATCACCTATCATATGAAGATATATTTATAAAATAGGAAACATATTAACCACTTATCATTTTATATATTTATGGTTTTATGTGTCAAAAATATATTGTTTCATGTATGTATTAAAGGATAAGTATGTATAAGAGGTTTTATAGATGTGTAAAATTATATATTTATACGTATCTTTACAAATTTAAGAATAAAGGAAGGAAAATTCTCAAAGAGGAATTCAGATATCAAGCAGTGCCCTTTGACCAAGAGCCTTGGTTACAACATACCTACAAAAGTGAACTATCATTGAAAGACCTATGGACACTGGATTTCTCTTTCCTTATTTAGAAGGGCAGTCTGTGTCTTGGAAAAGCATACAGTTTGTTGTATCTTGCTGGACAACAGGAGTCA';

if (2*$size*$count-$size-$count >= length($input)) {
    die "selection may not complete; choose a shorter length or fewer substrings, or provide a longer input string\n";
}

my @substrings;
while (@substrings < $count) {
    my $pos = int rand(length($input)-$size+1);
    push @substrings, substr($input, $pos, $size, $mark x $size)
        if substr($input, $pos, $size) !~ /\Q$mark/;
}
```

Comment: Very clear and simple answer. One question though, what is the purpose of the `\Q` in the regular expression?

Comment: Looks like it has a fairly unbiased distribution as well: http://i.imgur.com/EPLexRr.png.

Comment: in case you set $mark to something like '|'.  yes, this should be unbiased (but does refuse to even try if you are going to take much more than half the string)

Comment: Ahh, [I see](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#All-the-sequences-and-escapes). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursive approach in Python. At each step, randomly select from among the remaining partitions of the string, then randomly select a substring of length k from the chosen partition. Replace this partition with the split of the partition on the substring chosen. Filter out partitions of length smaller than k, and repeat. The list of substrings returns when there are m of them, or there are no partitions left with length greater than or equal to k.

```py
import random

def f(l, k, m, result=[]):
    if len(result) == m or len(l) == 0:
        return result
    else:
        if isinstance(l, str):
            l = [l]
        part_num = random.randint(0, len(l)-1)
        partition = l[part_num]
        start = random.randint(0, len(partition)-k)
        result.append(partition[start:start+k])
        l.remove(partition)
        l.extend([partition[:start], partition[start+k:]])
        return f([part for part in l if len(part) >= k], k, m, result)
```