# Get N random non-overlapping substrings of length K

Tags: python, string, random

Let's say we have a string R of length 20000 (or another arbitrary length). I want to get 8 random non-overlapping sub strings of length k from string R.

I tried to partition string R into 8 equal length partitions and get the [:k] of each partition but that's not random enough to be used in my application, and the condition of the method to work can not easily be met.

I wonder if I could use the built-in random package to accomplish the job, but I can't think of a way to do it, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random sampling of non-overlapping substrings of length k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655942/random-sampling-of-non-overlapping-substrings-of-length-k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop to enforce uniqueness:

```
import random
result, n, k = set(), 20000, 10
for _ in range(8):
  a = random.randint(0, n-k) 
  while any(a >= i and a <= i+k for i in result):
     a = random.randint(0, n-k) 
  result.add(a)

final_result = [(i, i+k) for i in result]
```

Output:

```
[(13216, 13226), (10400, 10410), (4290, 4300), (14499, 14509), (7985, 7995), (9363, 9373), (1181, 1191), (14526, 14536)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run a loop, and inside the loop use the `random` package to pick a starting index, and extract the substring starting at that index. Keep track of the starting indices that you have used so that you can check that each substring is non-overlapping. As long as `k` isn't too large, this should work quickly and easily.

The reason I mention the size of `k` is because if it is large enough, then it could be possible to select substrings that don't allow you to find 8 non-overlapping ones. But that only needs to be considered if `k` is quite large with respect to the length of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no need to do loops. If we want to split string `s` into `m` substrings with length `k` each, this problem is equivalent to sample `m+1` between-substrings intervals with total length equal to len(s)-m*k.

There is pretty good discrete distribution with the property that sampled values sum up to fixed quantity - [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). Splitting string by intervals is then pretty trivial, could probably be optimized

Code, Python 3.7.5 Anaconda x64, Win10.

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List

LoS = List[str]

def string2substrings(s: str, m:int, k: int) -> LoS:
    """
    split string s into m substrings with length k each
    """

    l = len(s)

    if l == 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Empty input string")

    if k <= 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Bad substrung length {k}")

    if m <= 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Bad substrung count {m}")

    if l < m*k:
        raise RuntimeError(f"cannot split string {s} into {m} pieces with length {k} - source length {l} is too short")

    if l == m*k: # trivial case of all zero intervals
        rv = [s[t*k:t*k+k] for t in range(0, m)]
        return rv

    # we will sample m+1 intervals which sum to l-m*k
    # for that we will use multinomial distribution which
    # sums to fixed value by itself

    p = np.full(m+1, 1.0/np.float64(m+1), dtype=np.float64) # equal m+1 probabilities

    intervals = np.random.multinomial(n = l - m*k, pvals = p)
    print((intervals, np.sum(intervals)))

    rv = list()
    end = 0
    for count, i in enumerate(intervals):
        if count == m:
            break
        start = end+i
        end   = start + k
        rv.append(s[start:end])

    return rv

print(string2substrings("qwertyuiopas", 3, 3))
```